# Jquery - If each() .filter working on console but not in code in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

**Context**:
I have a gallery of images. The user can select each image, when they click it, the "selected" attribute is added to the individual element and a new class is added to their chosen image.
The thing is, I want to limit this to only 2 selections being available.

I want to edit my script to only run up until the length is 2 or less. If the length reaches 2, no more Selected attributes to be added and no more class changes to be toggled.

I feel like I'm close. Right now my users can select/deselect but they can just do it too many times. Where am I going wrong?

```js
function NFTSelector() {

$("#NFTGallery2 > img").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      
      if($(this).filter("[selected]").length>=2) {
        alert('true');
    } else 
        console.log("less than 2 or undefined so letting them choose more");
     {
            $(this).toggleClass('chosenNFT');

            if ($(this).attr('selected')) {
                $(this).removeAttr('selected');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
            }

            
        }
    })
});
}
```

Comment: `$(this).filter("[selected]").length>=2` is never greater than 1.

Comment: your .each is superfluous, .click implicitly iterates over the collection. `$("#NFTGallery2 > img").on('click', ...` will perform the same task (this will not solve your problem, it just simplifies your code.)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach, I instead set it up as checkboxes and limited the checkboxes this way

```html
function NFTSelector() {
  var limit = 3;
$('#NFTGallery2 > li > input').on('change', function(evt) {
    if($('#NFTGallery2 > li > input:checked').length >= limit) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
}
```